# Adapted table width to text using pgfplotstable and csv excel

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, csv

I have a problem with forcing my table to the same width as the text. I export the csv (Excel) file to Latex using this approach, see code. Changing text-size in Excel works to a curtain "level", but the text want change more then what i get now, see pictures. I have tried a lot, but nothing works. Either i get errors or get the same width as now. Is there a simple way, notation, without changing the whole code.

```
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
    \caption{Maximum shear force}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=semicolon,
        columns/Element/.style={string type},
        columns/Joint/.style={string type},
        columns/M11/.style={string type},
        columns/M22/.style={string type},
        columns/M12/.style={string type},
        columns/MMax/.style={string type},
        columns/MMin/.style={string type},
        columns/V13/.style={string type},
        columns/V23/.style={string type},
        columns/VMax/.style={string type},          
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\toprule,
            after row=\midrule
        },
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{Mmax.csv}
    \label{tab:SlabMMax}
\end{center}
```

\end{table}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `resizebox` command from the [`graphicx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx) package:

```
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[

     ...
     }
```

Here's complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[showframe=false,right=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
    \caption{Maximum shear force}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        col sep=semicolon,
        row sep=crcr,
        columns/Element/.style={string type},
        columns/Joint/.style={string type},
        columns/M11/.style={string type},
        columns/M22/.style={string type},
        columns/M12/.style={string type},
        columns/MMax/.style={string type},
        columns/MMin/.style={string type},
        columns/V13/.style={string type},
        columns/V23/.style={string type},
        columns/VMax/.style={string type},          
        every head row/.style={%
            before row=\toprule,%
            after row=\midrule%
        },%
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{%
Element; Joint;M11;M22;M12;MMax;MMin;V13;V23;VMax\\
1;222;333;444;555;666;7;8;9;1010\\
}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. Though, it was not exactly what i wanted. By this the excel document is unnecessary?! This due to that the table is remade in LaTEX?! I "solved" the problem by making the table smaller (omit some data)...